# How can I find out which turtle is at a particular coordinate in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

How can I find out the Id of a turtle by the co-ordinate it is at some instant.
i.e if some turtle is at (a,b) which is known but I don't know which one then how do I find it.

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like:

```
let my-turtle one-of turtles with [xcor = a and ycor = b]
ask my-turtle [ whatever you want it to do ]
```

But turtle coordinates are floating point. So you shouldn't really be trying to check whether the value is equal to some number.

How do you know it is at (a,b)? If it's because it satisfied some condition and moved there, then why don't you label it as the one you want when it satisfies the condition for example?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming any turtle on the patch will do (or, if there is only one per patch):

```
to-report who-at-xy [#x #y]
  let _candidates [turtles-here] of patch #x #y
  if (any? _candidates) [
    report [who] of one-of _candidates
  ]
  report -1
end
```

That said, you almost surely should be working with turtles directly rather than with their `who` numbers.